# Shorten selected option in a select option list

Tags: javascript, jquery, selection

How can I shorten text in select using jQuery/JS? For example in the following select I want to display only letter 'G':

[image: select problem]

In contrast to: [Shorten long options in a select options list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15797865/shorten-long-options-in-a-select-options-list/15797961#15797961)  I want shorten only selected text not all options in popup list.

**UPDATE (Source of problem):**

I found where the problem was. SELECT element (in the figure) was located in a footer `TH` of table, which had `word-wrap:break-word;`. So this option was inherited from `TH`.

So finally I've chosen Volkan Ulukut's solution with normal wrapping:

```
<select id="currencies" name="currencies" style="max-width:35px; word-wrap: normal;">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I correctly understood what you want to do, but if you want to shorten the option's text directly, here's what you can do:

```
$('#your-select option').text(function (i, text) {
    return text[0]; //shorten text to the first letter
});
```

If you simply want to change it visually you can put a specific width on your select element using `max-width`.

Comment: This solution helped. I forgot to say in my question, that i had used max-width CSS option, but it had only changed width of component, but not selected text in it (as can be seen in attached image). However, example of Volkan Ulukut works fine in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

this would be a css solution but adding max-width to the selectbox should do the trick:

```
 <select id="currencies" name="currencies" style="max-width:35px;">
  <option value=gs>GBP</option>
 </select>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J5j39/149/)

if you insist on jquery:

```
$("#currencies").css("max-width","35px");
```